# Уведомления во flutter. Как реализовать?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Как реализовать уведомления во Flutter? Например, я хочу, чтобы пользователю приходило уведомление от приложения в определенное время.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если локальные (из своей бд.), то [Flutter Local Notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications). Если используешь Firebase то, [Firebase Cloud Messaging for Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging). Так-же есть от [OneSignal](https://pub.dev/packages/onesignal_flutter). У всех есть своя документация.

Comment: Не понимаю как работает flutter loacl notifications. Как с помощью него уведомления показывать. Даже пример не работает с гитхаба

Comment: [Android Integration](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#android-integration) и [iOS Integration](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#ios-integration) делали?